# Why is there a difference between ping "localhost" and ping "local IP address"?

Tags: windows, ip-address, ping, localhost

Using `cmd` and `ping` on Windows gave me the following results:

- Pinging "localhost":

[image]

- Pinging "192.168.0.10" (local IP address):

[image]

Aren't both situations exactly the same?

I mean, I'm pinging the same interface, the same machine and the same address. Why do I get such different results?

EDIT: Here is my `ipconfig /all` screen:

[image]

Comment: **You are not pinging the same interface**, even without any physical interfaces you still have a "local host".

Comment: If by "the same interface", you mean the loopback interface, you are correct. If you mean the Ethernet interface, you are wrong for several reasons. (For example, how is ::1 associated with the Ethernet interface? And why would the Ethernet interface -- whose job is to send Ethernet packets on the wire and receive them from the wire -- be involved in an operation that never involves an Ethernet packet or a wire?)

Comment: I'm fairly certain this question has been asked on Stackoverflow before, if I can find it...

Comment: The heart of this gets answered by this SO, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938039/localhost-vs-real-ip-address

Comment: I think the interesting thing is: why do you get a number of bytes transferred and a TTL when pinging a remote host, but neither when pinging localhost? Nobody likely cares that the IP address format is a bit off.

Comment: On mine I get Bytes transferred and  with both. I don't know if the difference with yours is IPv6 related

Comment: @David Schwartz The Loopback is an interface to a network. That is the internal network which does not need a Ethernet Interface, hence Tom Wijsman was correct.

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch: There is only one loopback interface, and it handles all IP traffic that is strictly local to the machine. How is it correct to say that "you are not pinging the same interface"?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**You are not pinging the same interface**, without any physical interfaces you still have a "local host".

Your `localhost` is used to refer to your computer from its "internal" IP, not from any "external" IPs of your computer. So, the ping packets don't pass through any physical network interface; only through a virtual loop back interface which directly sends the packets from port to port without any physical hops.

You might still wonder why `localhost` is resolving to `::1`, while traditionally we would expect it to resolve to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`. Note that `.localhost` is traditionally a TLD (see [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)) which points back to the loop back IP address (for IPv4, see [RFC 3330](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt), especially 127.0.0.0/8).

Looking up `localhost` using `nslookup` gives us:

> `nslookup localhost`

```
...
Name:    localhost
Addresses:  ::1
          127.0.0.1
```

Thus Windows prefers to use the IPv6 loop back IP address `::1` (see [RFC 2373](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt)) as it is listed first.

Okay, so, where does it come from, let's look at the hosts file.

> `type %WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts`

```
...
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
...
```

Hmm, we have to look at the DNS settings of Windows.

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852) tells us about a setting that affects what Windows prefers, emphasized in bold:

> 1. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
>    ```
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters
>    ```
> 2. Double-click DisabledComponents to modify the DisabledComponents entry.
>
>    Note: If the DisabledComponents entry is unavailable, you must create it. To do this, follow these steps:
>
>    1. In the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
>    2. Type DisabledComponents, and then press ENTER.
>    3. Double-click DisabledComponents.
> 3. Type any one of the following values in the Value data: field to configure the IPv6 protocol to the desired state, and then click OK:
>
>    - Type `0` to enable all IPv6 components. (Windows default setting)
>    - Type `0xffffffff` to disable all IPv6 components, except the IPv6 loopback interface. This value also configures Windows to prefer using Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) over IPv6 by modifying entries in the prefix policy table. For more information, see Source and Destination Address Selection.
>    - **Type `0x20` to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 by modifying entries in the prefix policy table.**
>    - Type `0x10` to disable IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces (on both LAN and Point-to-Point Protocol [PPP] interfaces).
>    - Type `0x01` to disable IPv6 on all tunnel interfaces. These include Intra-Site Automatic Tunnel Addressing Protocol (ISATAP), 6to4, and Teredo.
>    - Type `0x11` to disable all IPv6 interfaces except for the IPv6 loopback interface.
> 4. Restart the computer for this setting to take effect.

What is this prefix policy table?

> `netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies` (or `prefixpolicy` on earlier versions)

```
Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        45     13  fc00::/7
        40      1  ::/0
        10      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
         7     14  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1     10  ::/96
```

This table decides what prefixes get precedence over other prefixes during DNS resolves.

Ah, so using that KB we could add entries here that denote that IPv4 has higher precedence than IPv6.

**Note:** There is no reason to override this behavior, unless you are experiencing compatibly problems. Changing this setting on our Windows Server broke our mail server, so it should be handled with care...

Comment: Actually 'localhost' is not a top-level domain, but a hostname. The distinction is extremly subtle, but basically every domain name is a hostname, but not all hostnames are domain names. By convention, hostnames ending in a ful stop must be FQDN, and most hostnames not ending in a full stop can be converted to FQDN by appending the parent domain, falling back to appending the root if need. However, those are just conventions.  'localhost' is reserved by RFC 2606, to prevent it from becoming a TLD, since it is likely to not work right, and may even cause problems.

Comment: **Incorrect, as RFC 2606 mentions:** `The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.` Note the use of `TLD` and note that is *traditionally defined*. In fact, `ping localhost.` works which confirms that this is at least true in the context of this question.  Your very last sentence is not what the RFC said, please quote if it does "prevent it from becoming a TLD" because by what it says *it is* traditionally a TLD. Else they wouldn't refer to `the .localhost TLD`

Comment: I was a bit too strong. `localhost` can be a TLD if an actual DNS server responds for it, but generally localhost is generally defined as a hostname in /etc/hosts, in which hostnames are looked up prior to attempting to resolve via DNS. As such `dig localhost` usually does not return an "A" record for 127.0.0.1, or an AAAA record for ::1. That means the RFC is mistaken when it says `traditionally been statically defined in host DNS implementations`, but rather get returned by the system's name lookup service, which does not always use the DNS.

Comment: @KevinCathcart: We're in a Windows question here, and the Windows versions mentions this is done by DNS itself. `nslookup` does return records. So, YMMV...

Comment: @KevinCathcart my `dig` returns A, AAAA, and NS records for `localhost`, including an authority record for: `localhost. IN NS localhost.`

Comment: He's pinging the same interface, the loopback interface, in both cases. Ethernet interfaces only handle Ethernet traffic, they do not handle traffic that never involves an Ethernet packet and never goes over a wire.

Answer (score 20):

The [loopback interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_network_interface)  exists independently of your Ethernet interface(s).

Even without the complication of [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) you'd have two distinct addresses.

Loopback [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address : 127.0.0.1
Your Ethernet interface's IPv4 address : 192.168.0.10

The loopback interface might well be in a different software layer, more remote from real hardware. I doubt it depends in any way on your specific Ethernet interface driver for example.

Answer (score 12):

Localhost and your IP address are not the same thing.

The localhost is a special software only IP Address, that is linked to your system.  Localhost, or 127.0.0.1, is a loop back address.  It always points to your system, and is only accessible from your computer.  This routing occurs at the OS level, and definitely never leaves the NIC...  So there is no chance for it to hit the network....

Pinging your own IP address is similar but it potentially involves the entire networking stack, since it needs to detect that it is your IP address, and **route it correctly**...

The effect should be the same, but there can be differences.

For example, unplug your network cable.  Ping your static IP address.  You may get no route to host, or other errors.  Now ping localhost or 127.0.0.1, and it will work.

Comment: So, ping localhost is complete useless? I mean, if I want to test my interface....

Comment: @DiogoRocha correct, ping localhost does not touch the hardware ever. Heck ping 192.168.0.10 may not give you a reliable info too if the network card's driver intercepts requests given to itself.

Comment: @DiogoRocha Your terminology is off. 127.0.0.1 is an interface, but a virtual one.

Comment: @Diogo, Not quite.  Localhost allows you to test the network behavior of an application, or verify that the network stack is working....  But it doesn't test the driver.  So for example, if you have a bad NIC Driver, localhost might be able to help prove it's the nic driver.  Your mileage will definitely vary though!!

Answer (score 6):

I realize from the screenshots this question isn't about Linux, but it perhaps makes a useful "case in point".

On that OS, if you ping one of your local adapter addresses, it is translated to the loopback device (special case hack). This means that the packets actually go to the loopback device (which has all the implications you might think: for instance from a firewalling point of view, those packets are coming in on the loopback interface and will match rules for that interface).

The device to which the IP is assigned will never see the packets. (This is good because it would not do the right thing with those packets: it would want to send the suckers out.)

However, if the interface which holds that IP should happen to go down, you've lost that connection. The mapping to loopback will stop working.

So in other words, it is a workable design to regard those local addresses to be aliases for the loopback device.

Code references:

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.2/net/ipv4/route.c#L2623

Take a look at function `ip_route_output_slow`.  This calls `fib_lookup`, and if this function returns the code `RTN_LOCAL`, `dev_out` is rewritten to loopback:

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.2/net/ipv4/route.c#L2769

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the "Localhost" alias is resolving to the IPv6 loopback and when you explicitly use an IPv4 address obviously it doesn't.

Comment: My Ethernet Adapter have no IPV6 adress configured on it. Actually IPV6 is disabled on the wired interface.

Comment: The OS appears to disagree with you.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's apparently set up for the computer, localhost is hitting the ipv6 loopback.

Comment: @DiogoRocha There is no such address ::1 in IPV4 world.  127.0.0.1 is the IP reserved for the loopback there.  ::1 however DOES exist for IPV6, and like 127.0.0.1, is reserved for IPV6 loopback.

Comment: @DiogoRocha the loopback address doesn't go through a physical interface, so as long as your OS has IPv6 enabled it can be mapped to it. In Windows for instance, the mapping is done via a config file.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You're just stating the obvious.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, this doesn't really explain anything

Comment: so  ::1 is the IPv6 loopback address. good to know.

Answer (score 1):

@ebwhite is right about what.

Now, the why might be that you have [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) set up (I can't tell from your screenshot, piping it to a text file and pasting the whole output is better)  - the behaviour of localhost being [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) is consistent with the systems on my [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) only network with teredo installed, but systems without it behave as you expect it to getting `127.0.0.1` when you ping `localhost`. I've tested this with Windows XP and need to see what my Windows 7 systems do and update the question.

Generally, systems default to IPv6 if IPv6 is available so, your system is working as it should [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design).

Comment: he doesn't get Bytes transferred or TTL, with one of the screenshots, is that IPv6? why?

Comment: also consistant with what i see on windows 7 - my guess is the round trip time is negligible