# /etc/hosts entry of localhost not working on windows 8, it can't be over written

Tags: windows-8, hosts-file

I changed the /etc/hosts and added an ip address to point localhost to a different computer like:

```
192.x.x.1 localhost
```

But it is not working and when I ping to localhost it pings `::1` which is the default route

Adding an alternative name however works, its just the **localhost** that cannot be overwritten.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Localhost is probably built-in, though I couldn't promise that. If you use a different (unreserved or at least non-well-known) name, does THAT work?

Comment: @MarkAllen Yes they do

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the `localhost`'s IP address.

Note the comment preceding the lines in `hosts` file:

> **# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.**
>   
>   #    127.0.0.1       localhost
>   
>   #    ::1             localhost

So, you don't even need to enter `localhost` in your `hosts` file in order get it work, it's built into the TCP stack since it's a **[loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_network_interface)** address.

> In TCP/IP a loopback device is a virtual network interface implemented
>   in software only and not connected to any hardware, but which is fully
>   integrated into the computer system's internal network infrastructure.
>   Any traffic that a computer program sends to the loopback interface is
>   immediately received on the same interface.

Here are some useful [comments](https://superuser.com/a/414066/4464) from another answer on SuperUser:

> Your `localhost` is used to refer to your computer from its "internal"
>   IP, not from any "external" IPs of your computer. So, the ping packets
>   don't pass through any physical network interface; only through a
>   virtual loop back interface which directly sends the packets from port
>   to port without any physical hops.